# See what row caused "INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a `try...catch` for an `INSERT` to a table. Something like this:

```
try
{
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(conn, CommandType.Text, insertSql);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

In one of the many rows I'm inserting, there's one that fails with error *INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY.*

That's fine and all, but can the `Exception` return more information? Maybe it can return the value that failed the insert?

I understand that this can be done a zillion ways; I just want to know if I can get some information on the offending row without changing the structure or the `stored procedure` call (ie. add `OUTPUT` parameter) and with the `try...catch`.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
{
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(conn, CommandType.Text, insertSql);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(insertSql + Environment.NewLine +  ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This is really the most practical solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
 BEGIN TRY 
        BEGIN  
        --Do your update here
            SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
            END 
    END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH  
            BEGIN 
                    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
                    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
                    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

                    SELECT 
                        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

                    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                               @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                               @ErrorState -- State.
                               ); 
             END
            END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try - catch is good but not enough. You need to locate offensive rows.

```
begin try
insert...
select...
end try
begin catch
declare @badFK nvarchar(max)
select @badFK = (select fk_field from fk_table f
left join pk_table p on p.pk_field = f.fk_field
where p.pk_field is null
for xml auto,elements,root)
--raiserror as @vasmi recommend but include @badFK into message
end catch
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't see nothing about c#, but I suppose that you're using it.

In c# you can use this:

```
try
{
 // bla bla bla
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
 MessageBox.Show(es.ToString());
}
```

This error will continue what kind of error is (maybe a primary key duplicated, etc. etc.)

Comment: In this case, `SqlException` will return the same error as `Exception`, so this does not work.